# What happens if I try to enter russia 1 hour before my visa is valid

Tags: visas, borders, russia

Entering Russia is difficult these days, and the bus schedules are uncertain too, as is the queue to St Petersburg from Helsinki - which is my route.
If I'm fortunate and there are no queues, I might end up on the Russian side of the Finland/Russia border before my visa is valid. My visa becomes valid at 00:01 on 1. April, but I might at the earliest show up at the Russian border checkpoint at 31.03 23:00.

Will I be denied entry for an hour? Or worse, told to gtfo and never come into Russia again?

Comment: If needed, can't you just hang around the border for a bit to ensure that you won't enter early?

Comment: @PeterM: If you're crossing the border on a bus, you might not have a choice to delay your entry.

Comment: That is the situation @PeterM

Comment: @GregHewgill For some reason (mostly ignorance) I was thinking that you didn't stay on the bus when you crossed the border, and then joined a new bus on the other side.